# how can I export scraped data to csv - selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have 2 functions that are scraping data from google but I am not sure how to export my results into csv file with headers and links columns. Could you please help me with that?

```
def get_search_attributes(driver):

    headers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div/div/div/div/a/h3')
    headers = [header.text for header in headers]
    # print(headers)

    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div/div/div/div/a')
    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]
    #print(links)

    headers_df = pd.DataFrame(headers, columns=["headers"])
    links_df = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=["links"])

    return headers_df, links_df




def search_multiple_pages(driver, page_limit = 5):

    insert_search_value(driver)

    pagecounter = 0

    while pagecounter <= page_limit:
        get_search_attributes(driver)
        next_page_btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']")
        if len(next_page_btn) < 1:
            print('no more pages')
            break
        else:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'pnnext')))
            driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
            element.click()
            pagecounter += 1
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header_csv = headers_df.to_csv(..optional args)
links_csv = links_df.to_csv(..optional args)

f = open("filename.csv", "a")
f.write(header_csv)
f.write(links_csv) // or any order
f.close()
```

see [panda to_csv doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and [python write func](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) for detailing

Comment: thanks a lot, links right now under headers values, how can I change it in a way that it is a table with links and headers on the right?

Comment: @Adrian if you want in columns then you should create list of pairs `(header, link)` and then it will write every pair as row. You could use `zip(header_csv, links_csv)` to create pairs. OR you should keep all in one `DataFrame` as columns .

Answer (score 1):

You should put all in one dataframe using dictionary

```
#headers_df = pd.DataFrame(headers, columns=["headers"])
#links_df = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=["links"])

df = pd.DataFrame({"headers": headers, "links": links})

df.to_csv(filename)
```

---

Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Headers": ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
    "Links": ['https://A', 'https://B', 'https://C']
})

print(df)

df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Result:

```
  Headers      Links
0       A  https://A
1       B  https://B
2       C  https://C
```